# Concave-type question

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=x^p$, $0<p<1$. Let $a>0$. Is it true that
$$\forall x_1,x_2>0:x_1+a<x_2\;\;\; \exists p_0 \text{ s.t. } \forall p<p_0\;\; f(x_1+a)-f(x_1)>f(x_2+a+1)-f(x_2)?$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x_1+a)+f(x_2)>f(x_2+a+1)+f(x_1) \implies 2f(x_1+a)>f(x_1+2a+1)+f(x_1)$

this is not true.